# Como concatenar HTML dentro de PHP

Tags: php, javascript

```
<options += '<option value="' + j[i].CodCidade + '">' + j[i].NomeCidade + '</option>';
```

Estou com  esse código e quero adicionar mais uma atributo depois do NomeCidade, se alguém poder ajudar agradeço.

O código é um HTML gerado por JavaScript.

Tenho um select `cidades` e quero adicionar na tag `option`, depois do `NomeCidade`, o `ValorTarifa` que é recebido no mesmo `select` da cidade através do `CodCidade`.

O problema é: como colocar o `ValorTarifa` no mesmo option?

Funcionou com o exemplo que Baccon postou, obrigado a todos breve volto com mais duvidas.

Comment: Cara, você alterou completamente a pergunta. Melhor fazer uma nova, senão você invalida as respostas abaixo completamente.

Comment: Valeu pela dica

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Em JS

Você pode usar tanto o `concat` quanto o `+`:

```
 options.concat( '<option value="', j[i].CodCidade, '">',
                 j[i].NomeCidade, ' ', j[i].ValorTarifa, '</option>' );
```

O concat pode ser interessante neste caso, pois você pode usar com vários parâmetros, e tem a previsibilidade de ser tratado como string. Veja em funcionamento:

```js
var options = '';
var i;
var j = [
          { 'CodCidade':1, 'NomeCidade': 'Taubate' , 'ValorTarifa':'19,90' },
          { 'CodCidade':2, 'NomeCidade': 'Campinas', 'ValorTarifa':'25,00' },
          { 'CodCidade':3, 'NomeCidade': 'Queluz'  , 'ValorTarifa':'46,50' }
        ];

for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
  options = options.concat( '<option value="', j[i].CodCidade,'">', j[i].NomeCidade, ' ', j[i].ValorTarifa, '</option>' );
}

document.body.innerHTML += '<select>' + options + '</select>';
```

Usando `+=` e `+` também funciona neste caso. Só tem que tomar cuidado com problemas de interpretação quando misturar números e strings.

```js
var options = '';
var i;
var j = [
          { 'CodCidade':1, 'NomeCidade': 'Taubate' , 'ValorTarifa':'19,90' },
          { 'CodCidade':2, 'NomeCidade': 'Campinas', 'ValorTarifa':'25,00' },
          { 'CodCidade':3, 'NomeCidade': 'Queluz'  , 'ValorTarifa':'46,50' }
        ];

for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
  options += '<option value="' + j[i].CodCidade + '">' + j[i].NomeCidade + ' ' + j[i].ValorTarifa + '</option>';
}

document.body.innerHTML += '<select>' + options + '</select>';
```

<sub>resposta original, antes dos comentários e atualização da pergunta pelo autor:</sub>

### Em PHP

O operador de concatenação do PHP é o `.`

```
$options .= '<option value="'.$j[$i]['$CodCidade'].'">'.$j[$i]['NomeCidade'].'</option>';
```

Note que no seu exemplo, ele já estava sendo usado aqui: `j[i].CodCidade`, provavelmente por engano.

Será que você não quis dizer isto: `j[i]['CodCidade']`ou mesmo isto: `j[i]->CodCidade`? Além disso, se é PHP, estavam faltando os prefixos que indicam variável: `$j[$i]` etc...

Comment: `j[i].NomeCidade` tem cara de js :P

Comment: @rray pois é, tou achando que a tag tá errada, ou a troca de ambiente gerou confusão. Só espero que não seja PHP gerando JS, aí é traumático demais kkk.

Comment: Bacco e @rray: juntei mais uma resposta. Em JavaScript eu uso muito arrays para fazer strings. Assim evito concatenar :)

Comment: Eu não expliquei corretamente, esse código e um html gerado por javascript.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado a você a aos outros  pela ajuda. Agora vou tentar colocar os horários de cada rota pertencente a cidade

Answer (score 1):

Aqui ficam variantes diferentes para concatenar:

```
$codCidade = 20; // só para o exemplo, podias ter sando o $j[$i]['$CodCidade'] em baixo
$nomeCidade = 'Lisboa';
$options = '';


$options.= '<option value="'.$codCidade.'">'.$nomeCidade.'</option>';
$options.= "<option value=\"$codCidade\">$nomeCidade</option>";
$options.= "<option value='$codCidade'>$nomeCidade</option>";
echo $options;
// outras variantes :
echo '<option value=', $codCidade, '>', $nomeCidade, '</option>';
echo implode('', Array('<option value="', $codCidade, '">', $nomeCidade, '</option>'));
```

A primeira é no fundo o que procuras e o que o [@bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco) [respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107105/129).
A segunda é uma interpolação, usando aspas duplas escapadas.
A terceira é parecida com a segunda mas usando aspas simples (plicas) no HTML que [funciona na mesma](https://jsfiddle.net/1g1b2tzn/).
A quarta é uma maneira possível caso uses o echo isolado. Talvez não se aplique ao teu caso, mas é aplicável em casos semelhantes.
A ultima é como eu uso mais frequentemente em JavaScript. Criando arrays e depois concatenado tudo.

#### ideone (exemplo): https://ideone.com/foKFTL

Answer (score 0):

Isso parece um HTML sendo gerado por JavaScript. Então a coisa é um pouco diferente do que pede. Para fazer o PHP escrever isso, terá que escolher qual tipo de delimitador usar no PHP e então definir o delimitador que será escapado.

Exemplo, mantendo a forma original:

```
<options += '<option value="' + j[i].CodCidade + '">' + j[i].NomeCidade + '</option>';
```

Para colocar isso dentro de uma variável PHP ficaria assim:

```
$foo = "<options += '<option value=\"' + j[i].CodCidade + '\">' + j[i].NomeCidade + '</option>';";
```

Aqui usamos a double quote como delimitador, por isso, todas as double quotes da string devem ser escapadas com backslash

**Outro modo, usando [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)**

```
$foo = <<<HTML
<options += '<option value="' + j[i].CodCidade + '">' + j[i].NomeCidade + '</option>';
HTML;
```

A vantagem é que não precisa escapar nada, exceto em casos muito específicos.  Então basta jogar tudo na forma original.

Tome cuidado com o fechamento. No exemplo acima, `HTML;` não pode conter espaços ou tabulação no início.

Isso é bem mais limpo e prático para lidar com templates pois não precisa fazer escapes. É muito conveniente para atribuir códigos extensos onde daraia muito trabalho para fazer todos os escapes.

**Vamos complicar mais com um exemplo de [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)**

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<options += '<option value="' + j[i].CodCidade + '">' + j[i].NomeCidade + '</option>';
<?
echo ob_get_clean();
```

O output control é usado para casos específicos. Obviamente não usa-se para casos simples e corriqueiros onde podemos resolver com concatenação ou heredoc. Um exemplo de uso do output buffering é compilação de templates.

***termos usados:**

```
double quote -> aspa dupla
backslash -> barra invertida
```

Comment: Isso mesmo é um html gerado por javascript, eu queria adicionar mais uma variável na frente do NomeCidade que receberia um valor vindo do mesmo select só que eu não sei como concatenar as duas variáveis, e se isso e possível com a tag <option>